# Coimage of closed elements and coimage for galois connection between $Quot(X)^{op}$ and $Rel(X)$

Tags: category-theory, galois-theory

> Let be a morphism $f : c \to d$ in a category $C$ is the image of the corresponding morphism in the opposite category $C^{op}$.

Find what are the *coimages* of these 2 situations

**a)** Given a Galois connection induced from a relation as in def [3.1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Galois+connection#GaloisConnectionFromRelation), what is the coimage of that

> closed elements of $P(X)$ are precisely those in the image $im(IE)$ of $IE$ ?

I want *coimage* from that conclusion, because they are still talking about the  *image*.

**b)** Remember that in a [quotient object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quotient+object) $\ker$ (kernel pair) and $coeq$ (coequalizer) set up a Galois connection between $Quot(X)^{op}$ and $Rel(X)$ what is the coimage of the same

> Galois connection between $Quot(X)^{op}$ and $Rel(X)$ ?

---

For the second situation, I think that coimage of galois connection between quotient and relation could be just a *translation* of opposite category from quotient to relation.

> $Quot(X)$ and $Rel(X)^{op}$

In theory, it does not change the galois connection, but you should only move the opposite category between the 2 objects but I'm not sure and I don't understand the implication of this switch.

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. What do you mean by "coimage here?

Comment: This: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coimage - *The coimage of a morphism is the notion dual to its image*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to know what are the coimages of the closure operators associated to the two Galois connections you mention. But these are functions, so you want coimages in the category of sets : and these coincide with images, since every function can be factorized as a surjective one followed by an injective one, and these coincide with extremal (and even regular) epimorphisms an monomorphisms, respectively. So the coimages won't tell you anything more than the images already do.

Comment: mm.. interesting that coimages in the category of sets coincide with images. so we have a monomorphism, then an isomorphism, is so ? This seems a cover. Can we induce a split monomorphism  between monomorphism and isomorphism if we use coimages (not images)? My idea is to build spectral sequence of a filtered complex or *filtered* complexes

Comment: There may have been a misunderstanding : when I say that coimage and image coincide in the category of sets, I mean that the *object parts* coincide, the arrow parts are the two factors of the epi-mono factorization. That is, every function $f:X\to Y$ factorizes as $m\circ p$ with $p:X\to T$ surjective and $m:T\to Y$, and then $m$ is the image and $p$ the coimage.

Comment: mm..ok, but if a function can be factorized and if *I don't want* that object parts coincide, I don't want this coincidence (is more a divergence idea) so what should I need if coimage is not the solution that allow, instead, object parts *splitted* (= no object parts coincidence)?